# ECMAScript: Lexical Grammar vs Syntactic Grammar

Tags: parsing, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017, ecma

I am having some difficulties understanding the specific difference between `Lexical Grammar` and `Syntactic Grammar` in the [ECMAScript 2017](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-lexical-and-regexp-grammars) specification.

---

## Excerpts from ECMAScript 2017

**5.1.2 The Lexical and RegExp Grammars**

> A lexical grammar for ECMAScript is given in clause 11. This grammar
>   has as its **terminal symbols Unicode code points** that conform to the
>   rules for SourceCharacter defined in 10.1. It defines a set of
>   productions, starting from the goal symbol InputElementDiv,
>   InputElementTemplateTail, or InputElementRegExp, or
>   InputElementRegExpOrTemplateTail, that **describe how sequences of such
>   code points are translated into a sequence of input elements**.
>
> **Input elements other than white space and comments form the terminal
>   symbols for the syntactic grammar for ECMAScript and are called
>   ECMAScript tokens**. These tokens are the reserved words, identifiers,
>   literals, and punctuators of the ECMAScript language.

**5.1.4 The Syntactic Grammar**

> When a stream of code points is to be parsed as an ECMAScript Script
>   or Module, it is first converted to a stream of input elements by
>   repeated application of the lexical grammar; this stream of input
>   elements is then parsed by a single application of the syntactic
>   grammar.

---

## Questions

1. **Lexical grammar**

   - Here it says the terminal symbols are Unicode code points (individual characters)
   - It also says it produces input elements (aka. tokens)
   - How are these reconcilable? Either the terminal symbols are tokens, and thus it produces tokens. Or, the terminal symbols are individual code points, and that's what it produces.
2. **Syntactic grammar**

   - I have the same questions on this grammar as on the lexical grammar
   - It seems to say that the terminal symbols here are tokens
   - So by applying the syntactic grammar rules, valid tokens are produced, which in turn can be sent to parser? Or, does this grammar accept tokens as input and then test the overall stream of tokens for validity?

---

## My Best Guess

1. **Lexing phase**

   - **Input**: Code points (source code)
   - **Output**: Applies lexical grammar productions to produce valid tokens (lexeme type + value) as output
2. **Parsing phase**

   - **Input**: Tokens
   - **Output**: Applies syntactic grammar productions (CFG) to decide if all the tokens together represent a valid stream (i.e. that the source code as a whole is a valid `Script` / `Module`)

Comment: When it says *"... has as its terminal symbols Unicode code points..."*, I think they meant to convey "groupings" of one or more code points as described by the rest of the paragraph. It is a little confusing the way it's written.

Comment: Crazy Train: nope, each terminal symbol is a single Unicode code point.

Comment: @Magnus you really ought to accept Bergi's answer. It's spot on an this question is just sitting out here without the right answer being accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confused about what [terminal symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_symbol) means. In fact they are the *inputs* of the parser, not the outputs (which is a parse tree - including the degenerate case of a list).

On the other hand, a production rule does have indeed terminal symbols as the output and a goal symbol as the input - it's backwards, that's where the term "terminal" comes from. A non-terminal can be expanded (in different ways, that's what the rules describe) to a sequence of terminal symbols.

Example:

```
Language:
   S -> T | S '_' T
   T -> D | T D
   D -> '0' | '1' | '2' | … | '9'

String:
   12_45

Production:
     S          // start: the goal
   = S '_' T
   = T '_' T
   = T D ' ' T
   = T '2 ' T
   = D '2 ' T
   = '12 ' T
   = '12 ' T D
   = '12 ' T '5'
   = '12 ' D '5'
   = '12_45'     // end: the terminals

Parse tree:
   S
    S
     T
      T
       D
        '1'
      D
       '2'
    ' '
    T
     T
      D
       '4'
     D
      '5'

Parser output (generating a sequence of items from top-level Ts):
   '12'
   '45'
```

So

- The lexing phase has code points as inputs and tokens as outputs. The code points are the terminal symbols of the lexical grammar.
- The syntactic phase has tokens as inputs and programs as outputs. The tokens are the terminal symbols of the syntactic grammar.

Comment: Yep, thanks Bergi, I had understood that. In the lexing phase I assume we apply the lexical grammar repeatedly, to produce a set of only terminal symbols. What do those represent, following the lexing phase? Is the output (i.e. the remaining terminal symbols) now complete tokens? Similarly, at the start of the parsing phase, we take what was given to us by the lexer and apply the syntactic grammar once, in order to test the validity of the script/module. What comes in / out in this phase?

Comment: (Assumingly, for each grammar, there are terminal and nonterminal symbols as input, and only terminal symbols as output. What I don't get is what each of those in/out are for the lexical grammar phase vs the syntactic grammar phase.)

Comment: @Magnus No, the terminal symbols derived from the productions would be the *input*. When we say that "a grammar produces terminal symbols from a starting symbol", the word "Produce" doesn't mean "output", it means "is formed by". The outputs of the lexical phase are tokens, formed from non-terminal symbols in the grammar.

Comment: Thanks Bergi. I'm still struggling a bit with the order. So, in the lexing phase we start with code points and read them one by one to create tokens. That much I understand. How does the lexical grammar come into the picture here? Are the tokens actually the non-terminal symbols, and the source code points are the terminal symbols already? Then we construct the tokens (non-terminals) from terminal symbols?

Comment: The lexical grammar tells you what tokens (actually, input elements) to create from a given stream of code points. Every token produced by the lexical phase is an instance of a non-terminal of the lexical grammar (specifically, one of the InputElement start symbols).

Comment: @Magnus Yes. In the lexical phase, we start with code points which are the terminal symbols of the lexical grammar. Those are then parsed into a stream of tokens, represented by non-terminal symbols in the grammar.

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much guys. Super helpful. I'll give all a rate up.

Answer (score 1):

Your "best guess" is correct to a first approximation. The main correction is to change "tokens" to "input elements". That is, the lexical level produces *input elements* (only some of which are designated 'tokens'), and the syntactic level takes *input elements* as input.

The syntactic level can *almost* ignore input elements that aren't tokens, except that Automatic Semicolon Insertion rules require it to pay attention to line-terminators in whitespace and comments.

Your "How are these reconcilable?" questions seems to stem from a misunderstanding of either "terminal symbol" or "produces", but it's not clear to me which.

Comment: Great, thanks Michael. Yes, I guess I do not get exactly how the lexical grammar is used to create tokens in the lexical analysis phase. And similarly for the syntactic grammar/analysis phase.

Comment: The grammar on its own doesn't create tokens. Rather, you need a parser *based on the grammar* to do that. Note that, at least theoretically, you need two distinct parsers: one based on the lexical grammar to handle the lexical level, and one based on the syntactic grammar to handle the syntactic level. (In practice, the two are probably not that distinct.)

Comment: Yup, got it. As far as I understand, what's usually called the parser is actually the second stage in a compiler / interpreter. The first stage is called `lexical analysis` (done by a `lexer` using a `lexical grammar`). This stage crates the tokens and is further divided into a `scanner` and an `evaluator` phase. The `lexer` then sends the tokens to a `parser` (the second stage of the compiler), which will test the validity of the code as a whole using a `context-free grammar`, and then produce a `parse tree`. Later stages of the compiler might then produce actual machine code...